# How to rspec test swagger_api block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using swagger-docs in rails application, and define a action swagger_api as following:

```
  swagger_api :create do
    summary 'Create an account'
    notes 'create-account'
    param :body, :body, :JSON, :required, 'body'
    response :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

How to test the block of swagger_api?

More information: swagger_api is ClassMethods of a module, which definition as following:

```
module ClassMethods
  def swagger_api(action, params = {}, &block)
  end
```

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test the logic in the block of swagger_api, just like "summary 'create an account'", cannot find way to do that.

Comment: that does not make a lot of sense to me. why would you test the functionality of the library in your application? that should be part of the testsuite of the swagger-api gem.